# iwlwifi kernel error on kali linux

Tags: linux, kernel, kali-linux, iwlwifi

I install Linux with a bootable pendrive on a hard drive on my laptop. On the laptop I have also win10. During the installation pops up a notification that three files were not found on the removable drive: "firmware files: iwlwifi-8265-30.ucode, iwlwifi-8265-29.ucode, and iwlwifi-8265-28.ucode." My network card is an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265. On the intel website are only drivers 21, 22, 27, 31. 
The problem occurs during installation so any updates I am unable to upload through the commands from the linux console.

What should I do?

Comment: Select **No** and continue with the installation. Once you install kali, run **sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade**. The **iwlwifi** package will be updated with this process and so do the missing firmwares.

Comment: Seems like an Answer, @defalt !

Comment: But I can't run "sudo apt update" because i haven't linux console. This is problem. - @defalt

Comment: First complete your installation.

Answer (score 3):

Kali does  not ship with some wireless drivers. I have had this issue with my Broadcom card.

Complete the installation without installing any wireless driver. Skipping the wireless installation will drop you out of the automated walk through script and require that you to work through the list of installation tasks (setting time zone, partitioning etc) to compete the install.

If you are unsure how to do this then web search a walk-through, there are plenty.

When installation is complete boot into Kali and  connect to the internet (either LAN or USB tether). You should be root on first login (sudo if not) open a terminal and execute the following

- `apt-get update`
- `apt-get dist-upgrade`

If your wireless driver is not installed by the upgrade then install it specifically

- `apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi`

If you have an internet connection and the install fails then check the repositories in your sources file against the Kali website and try again.